# How to close a collapsed bar when clicking outside my navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nested navigation bar in my site, and it already works, however, I want to close the collapsed bar when clicked outside the bar.

Here is the javascript code I have:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav li').click(function() {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
  <ul id="nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="current"><a href="#body">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#aboutus">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Etc</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Etc2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Just use onclick function on element next to bar. e.g. after header if you have a section then set onclick on that section.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
$('body').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
                   if ($(".classname").is(":visible")) {
                       if ($(e.target).closest(".classname").length == 0 && !$(e.target).hasClass('active')) {
                           closeMobileMenu(menuobj);
                       }
                   }
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
  if(!$(event.target).closest('#nav').length) {
    $('#nav li').children('ul').slideToggle();
  }
});
```